# How do I show all buttons in a single line in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning Vue.js but I have a problem.

```
   <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody v-for="people in humans">
        <tr>
          <td>{{ people.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ people.surname }}</td>
          <td>{{ people.email }}</td>

          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-sm">
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm" >
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm">
            </button>
          </td>
```

style

```
<style>
  .table tr > td {
    border-top: none;
  }
  tr > td:last-child {
    padding: 7px;
    width: 80px;
  }
  tr > td:last-child .btn {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }
</style>
```

I've created 3 buttons on the vue js side, but the last button moves to the bottom. How do I show all buttons in a single line?

Comment: Your HTML/CSS has nothing to do with showing buttons in next line, its because column doesn't have proper width.

Comment: How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tbody v-for="people in humans">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ people.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ people.surname }}</td>
      <td>{{ people.email }}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-sm">
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm" >
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm">
        </button>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Besides it sounds like you have problems with width. Make sure that your table has the correct width to accept three buttons on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

```
       <td>
          <button class="btn btn-sm"></button>
       </td>
       <td>
          <button class="btn btn-sm"></button>
       </td>
       <td>
         <button class="btn btn-sm"></button>
       </td>
```

If that doesn't do it, then open the browser console and inspect your items. Maybe there's some margin or padding that pushes the last button to the next line.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question <style> </ style>. He also showed in one line, but there are plenty of spaces between them. Why is that?